# T-SQL Order by most relevant and most recent on top

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-search

I am using `ContainsTable` in my T-SQL statement to get most relevant content as per some given `keywords` in below query.

```
Select @Values = '"Keyword 1","Keyword 2,"Keyword 3"', 
Select @FirstLevelValues = 'Isabout ('+@Values+' Weight(0.7))'
Select @SecondLevelValues = 'Isabout ('+@Values+' Weight(0.3))'

;with cte as (
     (Select [Key], [Rank] from ContainsTable(PostsTable, Title, @FirstLevelValues))
     union
     (Select [Key], [Rank] from ContainsTable(PostsTable, Description, @SecondLevelValues))
) 
Select Top 100 P.* from PostsTable P
Left Join cte on cte.[Key] = P.ID where
P.PostDate between DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE() 
Order by cte.[Rank] DESC, PostDate DESC
```

Now my problem is that I have `[Rank]` column, which rates a Post from `PostsTable` on the basis of most relevant (most keyword matches has higher ranking). But, this should work in conjunction with `PostDate` column. Means the *most relevant and the most recent* Post should be rated higher than *only the most relevant post*. I do understand the concept of Order by, where one resultset is ordered basis one column first followed by the second column and so on. But in my case, I want that the `PostDate` should also be considered a criteria, probably with a `Weight` as in `IsAbout` clause, so it can also decide the ranking of the post.

Comment: What would be your criteria for weighting the `PostDate` column? Do you just want to order by that column first, then by `Rank`?

Comment: So what would your weighting be? Is a 5 day old post with a `Rank` of `100` higer rated than a 2 day old with a `Rank` of `80`? If so why?

Comment: @Charlieface, the issue here is, a 5 day old post might have the higher Rank as compared to a day old post. What I want is, like I have Weights for 'Title as 0.7' and for 'Description as 0.3', if we can add weightage for Dates too, so dates are also part of `Rank` calculation. Flipping the order, shows the most recent post which isn't really relevant.

Comment: Like I said: what *do* you want? How do we know how to "weight" it? A value doesn't have a "weight" unless you are doing full-text search, so you need some kind of logic to decide that. Perhaps `ORDER BY LOG(DATEDIFF(minute, p.PostDate, GETUTCDATE()))` or similar?

Comment: What I want is, if we give 20% weightage to date too for `Rank` calculation (make Title 55%, Description 25%), a post with 90% relevance will be rated lower than post with 80% relevance but is more recent so it gets 20% score for the more recent date.

Answer (score 0):

You can just flip the order of the `ORDER BY` columns to sort by `PostDate` first. But you need to change to a `JOIN` otherwise you will just get all `Posts` sorted by date.

```sql
SET @Values = '"Keyword 1","Keyword 2,"Keyword 3"';
SET @FirstLevelValues = 'Isabout ('+@Values+' Weight(0.7))';
SET @SecondLevelValues = 'Isabout ('+@Values+' Weight(0.3))';

with cte as
(
    Select [Key], [Rank]
    from ContainsTable(PostsTable, Title, @FirstLevelValues)
    union
    Select [Key], [Rank]
    from ContainsTable(PostsTable, Description, @SecondLevelValues)
) 
Select Top (100) P.*
from PostsTable P
Join cte on cte.[Key] = P.ID
where P.PostDate between DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE() 
Order by
  p.PostDate DESC,
  cte.[Rank] DESC;
```

I note though that you may get duplicate results if a `Key` is returned in both `CONTAINSTABLE` functions. You then need to also to take into account the higher of the ranks.

Instead you need either a `FULL JOIN`:

```sql
with cte as
(
    Select
      [Key] = ISNULL(t.[Key], d.[Key]),
      Rank = CASE WHEN t.Rank < d.Rank THEN d.Rank ELSE t.Rank END  -- be careful of NULL
    from ContainsTable(PostsTable, Title, @FirstLevelValues) t
    full join ContainsTable(PostsTable, Description, @SecondLevelValues) d
      on d.[Key] = t.[Key]
) 
Select Top (100) P.*
from PostsTable P
Join cte on cte.[Key] = P.ID
where P.PostDate between DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE() 
Order by
  p.PostDate DESC,
  cte.[Rank] DESC;
```

Or you can use two `LEFT JOIN`s.

```sql
Select Top (100) P.*
from PostsTable P
Left Join ContainsTable(PostsTable, Title, @FirstLevelValues) t on t.[Key] = P.ID
left join ContainsTable(PostsTable, Description, @SecondLevelValues) d on d.[Key] = P.ID
where P.PostDate between DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE()
  and (d.Rank is not null or t.Rank is not null)
Order by
  p.PostDate DESC,
  ISNULL(d.Rank, t.Rank) DESC;
```

The best option is probably to just use multiple columns in the `CONTAINSTABLE`, although this won't work if you want multiple weightings.

```sql
Select Top (100) P.*
from PostsTable P
Join ContainsTable(PostsTable, (Title, Description), @FirstLevelValues) ct on t.[Key] = P.ID
where P.PostDate between DATEADD(DAY, -5, GETUTCDATE()) and GETUTCDATE() 
Order by
  p.PostDate DESC,
  ct.Rank DESC;
```

Comment: Hello @charlieface can you please suggest the below
ContainsTable(PostsTable, (Title, Description). the fields mentioned in brackets are column names?

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax `CONTAINSTABLE(table, { column_name | ( column_list ) | * } , '<contains_search_condition>' [ , LANGUAGE language_term] [ , top_n_by_rank] )` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16